# Data before &(ampersand) truncated while parsing XML using SAX Parser

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing, saxparser

I am using SAX Parser to parse XML. In one of the XML tags, I have data like `abc&def`. While parsing the XML, I am replacing `&` with `&amp;`. But while parsing, all data before `&` is truncated. `&` and everything after that is retained in the truncated data. So `abc&def` will be converted to `&def` after parsing. Can someone please tell me a reason why is this happening???

Also, suggestions to overcome this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Michael Kay solution worked. Modify your characters method to append data public void characters(char[] buffer, int start, int length) {
                temp += new String(buffer, start, length);
            }

Answer (score 5):

The definition of the SAX interface, especially the `ContentHandler.characters()` method, says the parser is free to split the data into chunks any way it likes. This is for efficiency; it means it doesn't have to copy the data out of the I/O buffer before notifying it to the application. Parsers can choose where to split the data, but it's very common for parsers to split the text at entity boundaries. Your application is responsible for reassembling it: very often your characters() method should copy the data to a StringBuilder, and then you should process the assembled content when you get to the next start or end tag.

Comment: Does it result in loss of data??? As I have mentioned in the question, in my case, there is a loss of data where everything before the '&' is truncated and '&' and the data after that is retained. Pls advice.

Comment: No there is no loss of data. You haven't shown your code, but the usual problem is that people don't allow for more than one call on characters().

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is too late, but one workaround is to replace in the XML file all the ampersands symbols with a pipe symbol (or any other symbol you prefer)

Then, when parsing the xml file using SAX Parser add this line in the characters function:

```
content = content.replace("|", "&");
```

So it would look like this:

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        content = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length).trim();
        content = content.replace("|", "&");
}
```

This way you won't lose any data, and you'll have all the ampersand symbols you want.